# What is the 'selected' parameter in wp_dropdown_categories() for?

Tags: taxonomy, search, dropdown

I'm studying someone else's code (a custom search widget based on Elementor) and there's one thing I just don't understand.

```
$type_term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var($taxonomy), $taxonomy);
$type = (!empty($type_term) && !empty($type_term->slug)) ? $type_term->slug : 0;
```

```
wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                'show_option_all' => '',
                'show_option_none' => 'Select ' . $taxonomy_obj->label,
                'option_none_value' => '0',
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty' => 1,
                'depth' => 3,
                'echo' => 1,
                'selected' => $type,
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'name' => $taxonomy,
                'id' => $taxonomy . '-select',
                'class' => $taxonomy . '-select',
                'tab_index' => 1,
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'value_field' => 'slug'
            ));
```

I realize `$type` is the slug of the selected term.
But why do I have to manually assign `'selected' => $type`? What does this field even mean? Shouldn't this be automatically passed to the selected attribute? Am I even correct in that `get_query_var($taxonomy)`returns the selected taxonomy term?

Or more generally speaking, how/where is the selected option stored and how/where is it retrieved for the search? I'm sure there is something really obvious I'm not getting but the documentation didn't help.

I hope this is somewhat comprehensible. Thanks!

Comment: "Shouldn't this be automatically passed to the selected attribute?" Why would it? The current taxonomy term isn't always going to be what's selected. There's other use cases for this function.

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` parameter just defines which option is selected when the select field is rendered.
it's an optional parameter that defaults to the current category or 0

```
$defaults['selected'] = ( is_category() ) ? get_query_var( 'cat' ) : 0;
```

(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/)

This function is for rendering a category drop down, but you can override it to work with any taxonomy. It looks like your code is using an arbitrary taxonomy rather than a 'category'. So you need to provide the value.

In your code where is the value for `$taxonomy` coming from? What php template is this code running in?

Answer (score 0):

`select` is HTML attribute which say to browser to preset line to form. It's like user every time select from list one line, but can click on any other option after that. `select` is part of HTML returned `dropdown`.

> The selected attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an option should be pre-selected when
> the page loads.
>
> The pre-selected option will be displayed first in the drop-down list.

[w3school.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)